# Database not have consistent data after inserting data using hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have mapped two different POJO classes into single mysql table .Now when I inserting data Into that table it  stores data in two dirrent  rows under different Id , while i want to store both class's data into same row under same Id ,I have used a common Id(primary key auto_increment) for mapping both POJO classes.

Answer (score 0):

I know that parent-child relationship can be mapped into single table but mapping two different classes into single table that's something new. please add your mapping to see how you are doing it.
One way i think of is using a composition 
http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-component-1.html

Comment: Tell me about Parent-child relationship mapping  into single table

Comment: You can find more explenation in hibernate docs: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/